# How to properly Install mediapipe on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, raspberry-pi4, mediapipe

I tried to Install mediapipe for Python on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with Raspbian OS 11 (Bullseye). I have followed the expected Steps like "sudo pip3 install mediapipe-rpi4". Its successfully installed referring to the terminal, but when i try to import it in a Python file it returns a module not found Error. Is it because of the 64 bit OS?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a solution to this?

The solution posted at github here:
https://github.com/superuser789/MediaPipe-on-RaspberryPi/issues/10

Worked for me, and could get mediapipe working on the Raspberry Pi running either 64 bit or 32 bit bullseye. Be aware that this method results in the mediapipe install upgrading openCV to 4.6.0 which is not enabled for gstreamer so you will not be able to run the raspberry pi camera under opencv. It does allow running a webcam, in opencv, with mediapipe.

Getting mediapipe on the Raspberry Pi running Bullseye with the pi cam is proving to be quiet illusive.